# Insane CPU loads when watching web videos

Tags: firefox, video, freeze, cpu, youtube

after installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS video playback in browsers(Firefox and Chrome) is terrible. Pretty much any streaming service is affected. It's more like a flip book than a video. Audio seems to work fine during playback and quality settings in YouTube don't seem to effect the playback at all. `top` showed a max CPU load of 300%.

[%CPU > 300 in top while youtube playback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8TXK.png)

[The System:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvI3W.png)

- OS: ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- CPU: i3-3120M
- Graphics: integrated Ivibridge GPU
- RAM: 4GB

The system is pretty clean, I've only installed Pidgin, and Chrome for testing purposes so far.

Comment: I think it might be your cpu, a core i-3 is not the best someone could have. There are these problems in Windows too, with i-3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it figured out. It was a thermal throttling problem caused by `thermald` and this [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thermald/+bug/1600599) to be exact. So shutting down the `thermald` service did the trick for me. I still got CPU load greater than [100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SftZe.png) but video playback is now smooth.